# Minecraft Bukkit: Command not working

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am working on an essentials plugin for my server, but I can't get a 5th command.

Here is the code of Main.java:

```
package me.knightgeek.geekessentials;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.GameMode;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

public void onEnable() { //On plugin startup
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Geek Essentials has been Enabled");
}

public void onDisable() { //On plugin close
    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().info("Geek Essentials has been Disabled");
}

public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {       
    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "The console cannot run this command!");

            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length == 0) {
            player.setHealth(20);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been healed.");

            return true;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (target == null) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "This player has not been found.");
            return true;
        }
        target.setHealth(20);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been healed by " + ChatColor.WHITE + player.getName());
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have succesfully healed " + ChatColor.WHITE + target.getName());
        return true;
    }



    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("feed")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "The console cannot run this command!");

            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length == 0) {
            player.setFoodLevel(20);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been fed.");

            return true;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (target == null) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "This player has not been found.");
            return true;
        }
        target.setFoodLevel(20);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have been fed by " + ChatColor.WHITE + player.getName());
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have succesfully fed by " + ChatColor.WHITE + target.getName());
        return true;
    }



    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("survival")) { 
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "The console cannot run this command!");

            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length == 0) {
            player.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to survival.");
            return true;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (target == null) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "This player has not been found.");
            return true;
        }
        target.setGameMode(GameMode.SURVIVAL);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to survival by " + player.getName());
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have succesfully set " + target.getName() + "'s gamemode to survival.");
        return true;
    }



    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("creative")) { 
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "The console cannot run this command!");

            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length == 0) {
            player.setGameMode(GameMode.CREATIVE);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to creative.");
            return true;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (target == null) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "This player has not been found.");
            return true;
        }
        target.setGameMode(GameMode.CREATIVE);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to creative by " + ChatColor.WHITE + player.getName());
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have succesfully set " + ChatColor.WHITE + target.getName() + ChatColor.GREEN + "'s gamemode to creative.");
        return true;
    }



    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("adventure")) {
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "The console cannot run this command!");

            return true;
        }

        Player player = (Player) sender;

        if (args.length == 0) {
            player.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to adventure.");
            return true;
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);

        if (target == null) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.RED + "This player has not been found.");
            return true;
        }
        target.setGameMode(GameMode.ADVENTURE);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "Your gamemode is set to adventure by " + ChatColor.WHITE + player.getName());
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "[Geek Essentials] " + ChatColor.GREEN + "You have succesfully set " + ChatColor.WHITE + target.getName() + ChatColor.GREEN + "'s gamemode to adventure");
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

And here is plugin.yml:

```
name: GeekEssentials
main: me.knightgeek.geekessentials.Main
author: KnightGeek
description: The essentials plugin for GeekCraft.
version: 1.0

commands:
    heal:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Heals a player.
    feed:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Feeds a player.
    survival:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Sets your gamemode to survival.
    creative:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Sets your gamemode to creative.
    adventure:
        usage: /<command>
        description: Sets your gamemode to adventure.
```

The problem here is that it gives me the Unknown Command text. It gives me this when using the /adventure command. All the other commands work just fine. I have rewritten the code for this command, and still haven't found a way to fix it.

Maybe someone knows what I am doing wrong here?
P.S.: The indentation is wrong, I know. It is because I had to re-indent everything, and I was not planning on doing it. In Eclipse it is indented like it should.

Comment: Found the solution:
I was saving it as a disabled plugin, that I also made. So I couldn't use it.
**I am so dumb!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Op commented his solution, bringing it to an answer as it might help future users.

---

The situation was being caused because your plugin wasn't being exported as the plugin you expected it to be.

You were exporting it as a **different jar file**, which isn't in your server folder, therefore you couldn't test any new code added to the plugin.

A solution to that is simple:

When exporting your plugin from eclipse, **make sure you're saving it to the right jar file**, as the server will only read plugins inside the plugins directory.